# How To Include ONLY A Category

Tags: wordpress, blogs, posts

Client's wordpress is pretty customized and has had tons of stuff gutted and only functions can really be used. Any idea how to customize this:

```
<?php the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Recent_Posts' ); ?>
```

to only display a certain category?

Comment: That widget does not support limiting by category.  If you want to limit by category, you will need to install / utilize a different plugin or widget such as this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-by-category-widget/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured it out with my post below.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=1&posts_per_page=10' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<ul>
<li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></li>
</ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged.  Explain what you are doing, and why this solves this issue....